# Representing a free trial in structured data

Tags: seo, structured-data

Trying to set up the structured data for a software application on the website and am having trouble with how to represent a free trial as an offer if it is at all possible.

The product has a free trial for 14 days and then a tiered pricing scheme. The page with the structured data only has a button to say free trial, none of the tiers are listed. Can I put the tiered pricing in the structured data even though it is not on this page, it is on a different page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create two offers:

1. One offer is valid from now until two weeks expire, with the price equals zero,
2. Second offer is valid after two weeks are passed, with the regular price. Like this:

   ```
   "offers": [{
     "@type": "Offer",
     "price": {
     "@type": "PriceSpecification",
     "price": 0.00,
     "priceCurrency": "USD",
     "validThrough": "P2W"
     }
   },
   {
     "@type": "Offer",
     "price": {
     "@type": "PriceSpecification",
     "price": 6.66,
     "priceCurrency": "USD",
     "validFrom": "P2W"
     }
   }]
   ```

PS: `P2W`is duration of two weeks, as it is stated in the [ISO_8601#durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)